# How do I create a deeplink to a subsection of a web page?

Tags: html, hyperlink, deep-linking

Does anyone know how I can create a deeplink to a subsection of an individual web page?

Wiki seem to have it cracked but I can't seem to find the answers anywhere on the web.

PS: keep it simple!

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript? What do you mean by "Wiki"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Linking to a specific location or element on a page is possible only if the destination contains markup that constitutes a “destination anchor” that you can use in a fragment identifier (starting with `#`) in a link. The following create such anchors:

- An `id` attribute (on any element)
- A `name` attribute on an `a` element

The former is the modern, preferable way and lets you refer to an element, not just a location (point) or just an inline element. For example, if the destination page http://www.example.com/stuff.html contains

```
<div class="section" id="sec7">
<h2>Foo bar</h2>
<p>Some text.</p>
Any other content
</div>
```

then you can use a link like

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/stuff.html#sec7">Foo bar</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you wanted to begin a document with a table of contents that would link people to text that appear s later in the document. Your index would include the following:

```
<a href="#pt1">Part I</a> <a href="#pt2">Part II</a>
```

Later in the document, you will include the following tags:

```
<a name=pt1></a> and <a name=pt2></a>
```

Reference: [Links and Anchors](http://cti.itc.virginia.edu/~bcr/Labs/links.html)

**EDIT:**

Where ever you want to insert a link, write this:

```
<a href="http://yourpage.com#pt1">Part I</a>
```

Here `http://yourpage.com` would be replaced by the actual url to your page. Now in the code for your page, insert a tag at the point that you want your link to point to.

```
<a name=pt1></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Pulkit, however this does not provide an external deeplink into the page, only a link within the page. Do you know a way round this at all?

Comment: You can use `<a href="yourpage.com#pt1">` to define the link and  include the tag in your page where you want the link to point to.

Comment: Hi Pulkit, still no joy unfortunately.  Have tried inserting the <a href> tag in many places but no deeplinking occurs.  Are there any other ways around the problem that you know of?  Thanks

Comment: Could you please update the question with what you have tried? This should work.

Comment: I have tried multiple variants - too many to list.  Are there any rules as to where the <a href> tag should be placed?  Should it be left open?